# Making frirst EditText Cursor Visible

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a view like ContactEntry Activity as of native contact app. I have done this successfully but getting problem on edit text Selection. I want to first EditText(Organization Name) of First Row to be Cursor Visible but ListView makes the Edittext (Phone Number)of Second Row to cursor visible,Please find the attached Image also.

Please help me how can i fix it.[image]

Here is my Adapter class.

```
private class CustomItemEntryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

    public CustomItemEntryAdapter(Context context){
        mInflator = getLayoutInflater();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ItemsToFillViewHolder holder = null;
        if(position==0){
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.institution_name_cell, null);
            EditText edittext = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_institution);
            edittext.setCursorVisible(true);
        }else{
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.saving_account_cell, null);
        }

         if(position==1){
            if(map_CellView.containsKey(position)){
                convertView = map_CellView.get(position);

            }else{

                holder = new ItemsToFillViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(position);
                holder.cellTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_saving_acc);
                holder.cellTitle.setText("Phone");
                holder.cellImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_add);
                holder.cellImage.setTag(convertView);
                holder.cellImage.setOnClickListener(imageclickListener);
                AddDefaultCellToListView(convertView,position);
            }


        }else if(position==2){

            if(map_CellView.containsKey(position)){
                convertView = map_CellView.get(position);

            }else{

                holder = new ItemsToFillViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(position);
                holder.cellTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_saving_acc);
                holder.cellTitle.setText("Email");
                holder.cellImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_add);
                holder.cellImage.setTag(convertView);
                holder.cellImage.setOnClickListener(imageclickListener);
                AddDefaultCellToListView(convertView,position);
            }

        }else if(position==3){

            if(map_CellView.containsKey(position)){
                convertView = map_CellView.get(position);

            }else{

                holder = new ItemsToFillViewHolder();
                convertView.setTag(position);
                holder.cellTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_saving_acc);
                holder.cellTitle.setText("Address");
                holder.cellImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_add);
                holder.cellImage.setTag(convertView);
                holder.cellImage.setOnClickListener(imageclickListener);
                AddDefaultCellToListView(convertView,position);
            }

        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_institution);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 2):

also check in your xml if the second (Work) editText has a property of 'requestFocus'.
if so , remove it . (and move it to the first editText , as Muni suggested).